# How to Log an OutputDebugString via Log4Perl

Tags: perl, log4perl, outputdebugstring

it is possible to log all messages/levels with Log4Perl directly into an OutputDebugString (Windows System)?

I have some modules which use already log4perl, but now i want to use these modules in an environment where all log messages are OutputDebugStrings - in this environment the messages are read with DbgView and I want to read the output of my modules also with DbgView. I don't want to merge the Log4Perl Log files with the DbgView output.

I write OutputDebugStrings directly from Perl using the following perl code:

```
use Win32::API::OutputDebugString qw(OutputDebugString DStr);
OutputDebugString("Foo bar", "baz\n"); # sends  Foo barbaz\n to the debugger
```

I found the log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender - How can I achieve the same for Perl

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I know how to write OutputDebugStrings, but I want that all the log4perl logging messages go through OutputDebugStrings, how can Win32::API help me?

Comment: Hi, i updated my questions.                                          use Win32::API::OutputDebugString qw(OutputDebugString DStr);
OutputDebugString("Foo bar", "baz\n"); # sends  Foo barbaz\n to the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

==== found a solution ====
thanks to daxim i wrote my own appender. Here is the source

-generate a perl package with the following code

```
package Log4PerlOutputDebugStringAppender;

sub new {
   my($class, %options) = @_;
   my $self = { %options };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}

sub log {
   my($self, %params) = @_;
   use Win32::API::OutputDebugString qw(OutputDebugString DStr);
   OutputDebugString( "$params{message}" );
}

1;
```

-generate a Log4Perl config file with the following

```
log4perl.logger = INFO, OutputDebugString
log4perl.appender.OutputDebugString=Log4PerlOutputDebugStringAppender
log4perl.appender.OutputDebugString.layout=Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.OutputDebugString.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %-15.15c{1} (%4L) - %m%n
```

-initialize the logger in your Perl script

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
Log::Log4perl->init("logconf.txt");
INFO("INFO");
WARN("WARN");
FATAL("FATAL");
```

Et voilà - all logging messages go through OutputDebugStrings

Thanks daxim for help.